# Wicket AjaxNewWindowNotifyingBehavior and back button

Tags: javascript, java, wicket, wicket-6

I'm using `Wicket 6.x` and I'm having trouble with `AjaxNewWindowNotifyingBehavior`.

According to the Wicket documentation, this is what it does:

> An Ajax behavior that notifies when a new browser window/tab is opened
>   with url to a page instance which is already opened in another
>   window/tab in the same user session

basically, it alerts you when a new window/tab is created.

My problem, is that it is not working properly, because it doesn't trigger only on new window/tab, **but also when the user presses the browser's "Back" button**, which obviously is messing up my app's logic.

How do I avoid this? Is this a Wicket bug or am I doing something wrong? Here's how I'm using it:

```
add(new AjaxNewWindowNotifyingBehavior("compila") {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void onNewWindow(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        //Do whatever...
    }
});
```

Any ideas? Is there any way to detect whether the behavior triggered due to a new tab as opposed to a back button press?

Comment: Please create a ticket at Wicket JIRA with a quickstart! Thank you!

Comment: I just tried... and the bug doesn't trigger on the quickstart project, even if I'm doing the same things I'm doing in my app, and using the same wicket version :( I'm now trying to understand what I do differently, but I can't see what :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in AjaxNewWindowNotifyingBehavior:

It detects a new window, when an 'old' page is rendered into its original window, whose name has been changed by another page in the meantime.

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-6479

Comment: Thanks, I'm not working on that project anymore, but good to know.